# wordpress attack?

Tags: wordpress, botattack

I have 404 errors on Search Console when queries are being added to my regular URL, such as :

```
&sa=U&ved=0ahUKEwj56v3E9__KAhULbRQKHR3BDggQwW4IHDAD&usg=AFQjCNGDzpx5QNDQ5Kk8NJkIqs048na_tg
```

Any information on what this is and ways to stop it would be helpful.

Note that I do have Wordfence installed and it shows no issues.

Answer (score 3):

This could be anything. It doesn't look much like an attack (although it could be an attempt to pollute your search results - but it's a 404 anyway so no worries there, although it's polluting your reports).

Note that if GSC is reporting these 404s then it must have found and crawled these URLs from somewhere, either through a misconfiguration on your site or by someone linking to you in this manner.

Click on the URL in Google's 404 report and drill down to find out where these links are coming from - that should give you a big clue as to what's happening.

---

FWIW, `sa`, `ved` and `usg` look like URL parameters used in Google search. But why they would appear on the actual URL requested from your site is a mystery. A misconfiguration *somewhere* perhaps? Maybe there is a bot crawling Google SERPs and constructing (malformed) links from what it finds?!

Reference:
https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/42331/what-is-this-for-a-request

Comment: Thanks w3dk and sorry for the delay in posting. I voted it up but did not mark as accepted answer, as it does not actually resolve the issue. It's still going on and I keep on looking for a solution.

Comment: Did Google's 404 report provide any clues as to where these URLs are coming from? Do your own access logs report a referer?

Comment: Google's report is very poor on details. So, no additional data whatsoever. Only news is that it is not only Wordpress which is affected. My site is an hybrid wp+regular php and I now see the same pattern on the non-wp portion of it.